# How retrieve files in a minimal ubuntu installation? aka how apt-get retrieves files?

Tags: networking, apt, wget

I'm running pbuilder, which setup a minimal ubuntu installation, and I'd like to retrieve some files without «wget» (it's not installed by default), since apt-get can retrieve .deb files I imagine there must be a way

Comment: What do you mean by 'some files'? What files? where from?

Comment: any file http://example.com/foo.tar.gz | ftp://example.com/foo.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` uses a library, which you probably cannot use yourself since a minimal system likely does not include a compiler that you could use to build a program using that library.  Perhaps you should use `apt-get` to install `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: that's what I do, however what you say makes sense, I was just wondering if there was a way...